# AngularFire data not showing in list app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

While working my way through [Angular tutorials on their website](https://angularjs.org/#wire-up-a-backend) I got stuck when trying to create a list that uses [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) to store the data. Oddly, everything works on the Angular site, but when I click on the "Edit Me" link, nothing shows up in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ruw9n8y/1/).

I'm quite new to Firebase, but they aren't any errors in the console.

My Firebase database:
[image]

```
angular.module('project', ['ngRoute', 'firebase'])

.value('fbURL', 'https://angular-project-list.firebaseio.com/')
.service('fbRef', function(fbURL) {
  return new Firebase(fbURL)
})
.service('fbAuth', function($q, $firebase, $firebaseAuth, fbRef) {
  var auth;
  return function () {
      if (auth) return $q.when(auth);
      var authObj = $firebaseAuth(fbRef);
      if (authObj.$getAuth()) {
        return $q.when(auth = authObj.$getAuth());
      }
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      authObj.$authAnonymously().then(function(authData) {
          auth = authData;
          deferred.resolve(authData);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
  }
})

.service('Projects', function($q, $firebase, fbRef, fbAuth) {
  var self = this;
  this.fetch = function () {
    if (this.projects) return $q.when(this.projects);
    return fbAuth().then(function(auth) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var ref = fbRef.child('projects-fresh/' + auth.auth.uid);
      var $projects = $firebase(ref);
      ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.val() === null) {
          $projects.$set(window.projectsArray);
        }
        self.projects = $projects.$asArray();
        deferred.resolve(self.projects);
      });

      //Remove projects list when no longer needed.
      ref.onDisconnect().remove();
      return deferred.promise;
    });
  };
})

.config(function($routeProvider) {
  var resolveProjects = {
    projects: function (Projects) {
      return Projects.fetch();
    }
  };

  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      controller:'ProjectListController as projectList',
      templateUrl:'list.html',
      resolve: resolveProjects
    })
    .when('/edit/:projectId', {
      controller:'EditProjectController as editProject',
      templateUrl:'detail.html',
      resolve: resolveProjects
    })
    .when('/new', {
      controller:'NewProjectController as editProject',
      templateUrl:'detail.html',
      resolve: resolveProjects
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo:'/'
    });
})

.controller('ProjectListController', function(projects) {
  var projectList = this;
  projectList.projects = projects;
})

.controller('NewProjectController', function($location, projects) {
  var editProject = this;
  editProject.save = function() {
      projects.$add(editProject.project).then(function(data) {
          $location.path('/');
      });
  };
})

.controller('EditProjectController',
  function($location, $routeParams, projects) {
    var editProject = this;
    var projectId = $routeParams.projectId,
        projectIndex;

    editProject.projects = projects;
    projectIndex = editProject.projects.$indexFor(projectId);
    editProject.project = editProject.projects[projectIndex];

    editProject.destroy = function() {
        editProject.projects.$remove(editProject.project).then(function(data) {
            $location.path('/');
        });
    };

    editProject.save = function() {
        editProject.projects.$save(editProject.project).then(function(data) {
           $location.path('/');
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: A link to your JSFiddle would help people diagnose the problem.

Comment: @JamesTalmage updated

Comment: I get an error immediately in the console from your fiddle. `Firebase.set failed: First argument contains undefined`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing some data from the tutorial. Add this to the beginning of your script:

```
window.projectsArray = [
  {
    "name": "AngularJS",
    "site": "http://angularjs.org",
    "description": "HTML enhanced for web apps!"
  },
  {
    "name": "jQuery",
    "site": "http://jquery.com/",
    "description": "Write less, do more."
  },
  {
    "name": "Backbone",
    "site": "http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/",
    "description": "Models for your apps."
  },
  {
    "name": "SproutCore",
    "site": "http://sproutcore.com/",
    "description": "Innovative web-apps."
  },
  {
    "name": "Sammy",
    "site": "http://sammyjs.org/",
    "description": "Small with class."
  },
  {
    "name": "Spine",
    "site": "http://spinejs.com/",
    "description": "Awesome MVC Apps."
  },
  {
    "name": "Cappucino",
    "site": "http://cappuccino.org/",
    "description": "Objective-J."
  },
  {
    "name": "Knockout",
    "site": "http://knockoutjs.com/",
    "description": "MVVM pattern."
  },
  {
    "name": "GWT",
    "site": "https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/",
    "description": "JS in Java."
  },
  {
    "name": "Ember",
    "site": "http://emberjs.com/",
    "description": "Ambitious web apps."
  },
  {
    "name": "Batman",
    "site": "http://batmanjs.org/",
    "description": "Quick and beautiful."
  }
]
```

Comment: please see updated question that uses my personal firebase account. as you can see there is content there, but it's not coming though.

Comment: @itsclarke That's because that's not how this code works. Data is retrieved from `'projects-fresh/' + auth.auth.uid`. If it's not present, then the code puts data there from the array @James Talmage posted.  You'd be better off writing a project from scratch than using this undocumented code.

Comment: You need to enable anonymous authentication for that Firebase.